# Flutter Firebase - Allow null `request.auth.uid` to read collection documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

A social media-type application that I'm developing allows the user to select a unique username upon signup, the only issue is that the app handles username novelty verification client side.  That is to say that the app retrieves all usernames from the relevant collection, and checks whether or not the requested username already exists within that list.

Unfortunately, with the way my firebase security rules are set up (please see below), the user must first exist before this aforementioned 'username novelty verification' can take place.

This means that no matter if the username is unique or not, the user is given an account under their desired email address first.  This results in accounts being setup that have failed this verification, and have a subsequently `null` username field.

I understand that handling username verification client-side is inefficient at best, and dirty at worst, so if you could suggest any 'Firebase-side' verification methods, perhaps using Firebase 'Functions', that would be awesome.

Thanks

---

**Firebase security rules:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userID} {
      allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update, write, delete: if (
        (
            request.resource.data.email == resource.data.email &&
             request.resource.data.id == resource.data.id && 
               request.auth.uid == userID
        ) && 
            (request.resource.data.userBio != resource.data.userBio ||
              request.resource.data.username != resource.data.username || 
                request.resource.data.location != resource.data.location ||
                 request.resource.data.favPlaces != resource.data.favPlaces ||
                   request.resource.data.following != resource.data.following ||
                     request.resource.data.likedTrips != resource.data.likedTrips)
      );
    }
...
```

**Email signup routine:**

```
Future signUpWithEmail({
    @required String email,
    @required String password,
    @required String username,
    @required String userBio,
    @required List favPlaces,

    @required BuildContext context,

  }) async {

    var authResult;

    try {
      authResult = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      sendUserEmailVerification(authResult.user);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }

    final CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final documents = await collectionReference.where("username").get();

    List results = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < documents.docs.length; i++) {
      results.add(documents.docs[i]["username"]);
    }

    if (!results.contains(username)) {
      if (favPlaces.toString() != "[]") {
        try {

          await _firestoreService.createUser(
            TRUser(
              id: authResult.user.uid,
              email: email,
              username: username,
              userBio: userBio,
              following: [],
              favPlaces: favPlaces,
              likedTrips: []
            )
          );

          Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomePage(username:username)));
          
          return authResult.user != null;

        } catch (e) {
          return e;

        }
      } else {

        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text("please select at least 1 location"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                isDefaultAction: true,
                child: Text('okay'),
              )
            ],
          )
        );

      }
    } else {
      
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: Text("this username is already in use"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            CupertinoDialogAction(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              isDefaultAction: true,
              child: Text('okay'),
            )
          ],
        )
      );

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users are authenticating first, then taken to create a unique username, then there's a solution for your problem.

Create a new collection that has a document that contains only usernames. You use one document to save up on costs from reads, because every new user will request a get() for this doc.

On the top of your rules, you create a rule for this connection, where you allow only authenticated users to read it.

After it's download, you can do your check to validate if the name is unique or not, if the user finishes up, you add this newly created username to this document,.so other new users stay updated.

Comment: It’s late in my country, but I’ll let you know my thoughts in a while 

Comment: Sorry for my delay, this is a great workaround.

Comment: To save on data, I'm thinking that each document in this separate `registered_usernames` collection shares the same `documentID` as the corresponding document in the `users` collection.  Do you see any potential conflict with this?

Comment: I don't see any conflicts, but what is the rationale for doing so?

Comment: So that each document only needs a `username` field, rather than a `username` and `userID` field.

Comment: I would suggest having only one document, call it `(registerdNames)`, inside the `collection (registerdNames)`. 
This document will have a single field, called for example `'names'`.
When you access 'names', it returns a List<String>, that has all the registered usernames. To make it clear, you access it like this:

`DocumentSnapshot docTemp = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('registerdNames').doc('registerdNames').get();`

Then=> `List names = docTemp.data()['names'];`

Comment: Does this solution save much data over what I've proposed, or are there other reasons why this would be more desirable?

Comment: From what I understood, you want to create a separate document for every user who registered, to keep track of the username they used, is that correct? If yes, then that means if you have 1K users, you will have 1k documents in `registeredNames`, one for every user. When I want to sign up to your site now, your code will have to check if the user name i went to use is already taken or not.. to do that, you will be billed for 1K document reads. And the same thing for every new user 1k reads.What I suggested, is to have a single document that has all the registered users.Billed for 1 get request

Comment: There is a size limit to every document, 1 mb. But 1 mb can store lots of UIDs, roughly 800K characters, including the indexes. Which is probably enough to hold 50K nick names. You can create a new document for every 10k users. But if your app has this number of users, you wouldn't be worried about being billed for $0.06 per every 100K get request, and could be cheaper in other dara center locations.

Comment: This is great advice, I was working under the false premise that to read each datapoint you retrieve from the sum of the selected documents in a collection, you incurred one request.  I've been stressing over the idea of 'if you have 1M users, and gain 1K per day, you'd perform 1B+ requests on username verification in a single day '.  I still have to consider the 1MB file limit, but as you point out, if I exceed this limit I'm probably running a big enough service to no worry about this in relation to financial cost.

Comment: I'm not sure currently regarding another aproach, you can store the nickName inside the original document, along with their phone and email..etc. whenever you have a new user, you run a query and use `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('userName', isEqualTo: "theNewName").get();` . The result of this query is a list of docs. Ideally, for the current signup process to continue, this query should not contain any results, and docs.isEmpty should be true, and that'll mean that the username isn't taken and can be allowed to register. This is actually a cleaner approach.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot that you don't want them to read the database this is the whole point. But if the above method is billed based on number of documents being quiried or on the number of documents in the results, I'll have to check.

Comment: No worries, I was using this same method beforehand which as you pointed out, doesn’t work well with the original issue expressed in my OP.  Thanks for your help with this!